# Why an empty report is being created in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to Jasper Reports , cpuld anybody please tell me why an empty Report is being created inspite of data being resent in Database

please see this is my program

```
public class ReportDriver {

    /**
     * Constructor for ReportDriver
     */
    public ReportDriver() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcle", "scott", "tiger");

            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader
                    .load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Admin\\report5.jrxml");

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(jasperDesign);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                    jasperReport, null, con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            String connectMsg = "Could not create the report ";
            System.out.println(connectMsg);
        }
    }

}
This is my jrxml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report5" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select EMPNO , ENAME ,  JOB from emp]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EMPNO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ENAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="JOB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your report is empty because that's exactly how it should be: Your jrxml does not include any elements to display. Try the following jrxml and see the difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report5" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select EMPNO , ENAME ,  JOB from emp]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EMPNO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ENAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="JOB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{EMPNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ENAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{JOB}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```